# where does the data of any react form get stored

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have coded this so how to fetch the data as I have added social logins and phone so I have query where data gets stored in reactjs and how I have to fetch data I want e-mail and phone number and name when somebody login so that I can integrate apis

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import firebase from "firebase"
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth"

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBPqAebQzVeT5Kbd57TsDwoF_l3pRCVomY",
    authDomain: "login-project-d33bf.firebaseapp.com"
})

class SocialLogin extends Component {
    state = { isSignedIn: false }
    uiConfig = {
        signInFlow: "popup",
        signInOptions: [
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PHONE_SIGN_IN_METHOD,
        ],
        callbacks: {
            signInSuccess: () => false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user })
            console.log("user", user)

            firebase.database().ref("signInSuccess").on("value", snapshot => {
                let signInSuccess = [];
                snapshot.forEach(snap => {
                    signInSuccess.push(snap.val());
                })
                this.setState({signInSuccess : signInSuccess})
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.isSignedIn ? (
                    <span>
                <div>Signed In!</div>
                <button onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign out!</button>
                <h1>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}</h1>
                <img
                    alt="profile picture"
                    src={firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL}
                />
              </span>
                ) : (
                    <StyledFirebaseAuth
                        uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
                        firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
                    />
                )}


                {this.state.signInSuccess.map(data =>{

                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{data.email}</td>
                            <td>{data.mobilenumber}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SocialLogin
```

so where does the data get store because I have to fetch the data from the code so I have to fetch data useremail and phonenumber and name so  how can I do it?

Comment: the code I  wrote above is showing error that TypeError map property not found

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is occurring because `this.state.signInSuccess` is not an array. May be good to check if `this.state.signInSuccess` is an array with data prior to perform the `.map`

```
render() {
    const { signInSuccess, isSignedIn } = this.state;
    const isSignInSuccess = Array.isArray(signInSuccess);

        return (
            <div className="App">
                {isSignedIn ? (
                    <span>
                <div>Signed In!</div>
                <button onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign out!</button>
                <h1>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}</h1>
                <img
                    alt="profile picture"
                    src={firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL}
                />
              </span>
                ) : (
                    <StyledFirebaseAuth
                        uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
                        firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
                    />
                )}


                {isSignInSuccess && isSignInSuccess.map(data =>{
                    return (
                      <tr>
                          <td>{data.email}</td>
                          <td>{data.mobilenumber}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I tried what you said still it is giving errors @eagercoder

Comment: my code which I have written it is working but my main question is that I want to fetch data on the screen that credentials if anyone signs in with an email  his email id shows and if he signs with phone number his phone number shows on the screen so I can integrate the api

Comment: if anyone wants to connect i am ready to connect

Comment: I used the code but it is showing this error SyntaxError: C:\data-fetch\src\sociallogin.js: Missing semicolon.

Comment: How are you importing `SocialLogin`?